# Map size different in before update and after update triggers

Tags: triggercontext

I've come across a null pointer exception. After I started diggin in, I realized that before update contains 163 records where as after update contains only 161 records. I have never encountered such a scenario. Can some one educate me about the possible scenarios for dropping some records in after trigger?

Thanks..

Comment: one possibility -- You are doing a batch operation that allows for partial successes. 2 failures in validation or addError() during beforeUpdate

Comment: I thought of that possibility. But shouldn't it throw validation error instead of null pointer( which is caused at a later point in time)?

Comment: is your `after update` trigger relying on some List retained from the `before update` trigger? That could be the cause of an NPE - you'll need to post more info

Comment: Yes. I'm building a wrapper in before trigger which is being used in the after trigger..Also I think as you said in the first comment, looks like validations are the cause for dropping the 2 records....I'll get back once I confirm that. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @crop1645 It doesn't even need to be a allOrNone, so long as at least one record survives. This actually kind of surprised me, as I thought the restart would occur sooner, but... there you have it. Proof that a single before/after trigger pair can have different sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of your records did not survive because of validation rules, unique error constraints, addError messages, or other situations that could arise. This situation happens when the allOrNone attribute is set to false. As an exercise, I created a simple trigger that fails one record if there are two records in the transaction.

```
trigger accountBeforeAfterTrg on Account (before insert, after insert) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, Trigger.isBefore?'Before Insert':'After Insert');
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, Trigger.size);
    if(Trigger.size==2) {
        Trigger.new[1].addError('You fail.');
    }
}
```

Then, I use the "allOrNone" flag to cause a restart (in Execute Anonymous):

```
Database.insert(new Account[] { new Account(Name='Test 1'), new Account(Name='Test 2') }, false);
```

And, finally, I open the resulting debug log (omitting parts that don't matter, for brevity):

```
13:37:30.149 (149935837)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|Before Insert
13:37:30.149 (149994493)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|2
13:37:30.268 (268851713)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|After Insert
13:37:30.268 (268879590)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|1
13:37:30.290 (290323774)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|Before Insert
13:37:30.290 (290350911)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|1
13:37:30.346 (346104254)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|After Insert
13:37:30.346 (346133636)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|1
```

As you can see, the trigger ran a total of four times; twice before, and twice after, and during the first one, the size was different.

If you use the default mode, where allOrNone is set to true, then you can still experience a debug statement where the sizes are different before and after:

```
13:41:47.106 (106070134)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|Before Insert
13:41:47.106 (106154735)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|2
13:41:47.302 (302051777)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|After Insert
13:41:47.302 (302080020)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|1
```

Therefore, you must guard against the possibility that not all records that were available in a before trigger will exist in an after-trigger; even after a restart, things will still be as they were earlier. One final piece of code demonstrates this:

```
public class holdStat {
    public static Account[] values;
}

trigger accountBeforeAfterTrg on Account (before insert, after insert) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, Trigger.isBefore?'Before Insert':'After Insert');
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, Trigger.size);
    if(holdStat.values == null) {
        holdStat.values = Trigger.new.clone();
    }
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Hold Stat size: '+holdStat.values.size());
    if(Trigger.size==2) {
        Trigger.new[1].addError('You fail.');
    }
}
```

And the related debug logs:

```
13:46:38.129 (129126408)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|Before Insert
13:46:38.129 (129209728)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|2
13:46:38.130 (130491038)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|ERROR|Hold Stat size: 2
13:46:38.291 (291065190)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|After Insert
13:46:38.291 (291114253)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|1
13:46:38.291 (291200778)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|ERROR|Hold Stat size: 2
13:46:38.307 (307601147)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|Before Insert
13:46:38.307 (307642397)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|1
13:46:38.307 (307727343)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|ERROR|Hold Stat size: 2
13:46:38.358 (358754898)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|After Insert
13:46:38.358 (358783443)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|1
13:46:38.358 (358845452)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|ERROR|Hold Stat size: 2
```

Notice how my static variable *knows* there's two records, but my *after insert* trigger executions only see one.

It doesn't have to be an error you generated, either. It could have been a unique constraint, a field that was required being blanked out, etc.

Comment: Great answer; the restart gave me quite a fit once - see http://cropredysfdc.com/2015/04/26/245/ - SFDC doc actually covers the static variable issue - it was something I had never read before

Comment: It was a validation error as quoted by @crop1645. Thank you very much for the explanation :)